# Returning a by value with operator <<

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

So, I've had this problem for a while now.

```
std::vector<std::string> operator<<(std::vector<std::string>& vec, std::string const& x)
{
    vec.push_back(x);
    return vec;
}
```

I just can't seem to understand this. I'm taking a reference to a vector, as well as constant to x and I'm returning a vector and in this case, I'm actually copying the return value, but why this can be such a problem ? Just copying some bytes in plus.

The interesting part comes here :

```
vec << string << string ; // This doesn't work, but
vec << string; 
vec << string; // This does !
```

I can't understand where the problem could be, I hope someone can help me out.

Comment: change `std::vector<std::string> operator<<` to `std::vector<std::string>& operator<<`. Also, did you try using a debugger?

Comment: You want to return by reference, not by value.

Comment: There may be some caveats against operator overloads that consist only of standard types, rather than involving at least one of your own types.  For a toy program just for fun, these kinds of experiments are okay (and educational).  I'd recommend avoiding these kinds of gratuitous operator overloads for production code.  (Boost probably has something that does this sort of thing with operator overloads -- your call as to whether-or-not to use Boost.)

Comment: On an unrelated note, it is evil to name objects of `std::string` as `string`

Comment: @Ивелин Иванов I should make a suggestion, can you not randomly define the operators and follow normal programming conventions, usually << is meant as output from cout, it is just like defining + on a string to multiply the integer complements of strings together, it is confusing....

Answer (score 3):

The entire point of that return value is to be able to chain the `<<` calls and run them on the very same object, which isn't the case in your example. Lets try and think what happens when you try the `vec << string << string` code while retuning a value instead of a reference.

1. You have a `vec` object, and call it's `operator<<` with the first string argument, which is perfectly fine
2. The `operator<<` does it's job, **creates a copy of vec**, and returns this temporary copy.
3. This **temporary copy** got it's `operator<<` called with the second string
4. The `operator<<` does it's job, but it does so on the **temporary copy**
5. The temporary copy is **discarded**

Of course it works when you call the `<<` twice without chaining it, because in this case you are just manually calling it on the correct object, and simply discarding temporary copies returned by the method.

Hope it makes things clear.

Comment: Sorry, but isn't it working like : ((vec << string) << string). So when I return the copy in vec the other is returning to the vec too ?

Comment: Think about the << as if it would be a simple method call (which it actually is, btw), lets say the method name is `foo`. So basically, a single, non-chained, call is a `vec.foo(string)`. The second call is on the object **returned by the first call**, so basically `(vec.foo(string)).foo(string)`, the second `foo` is called on whatever the first foo returns. You return a copy? It is called on a copy!

Answer (score 1):

To concatenate function calls, you need to return the same object and not its copy.
So, `std::vector<std::string> operator<<` actually returns a copy. However, `std::vector<std::string>& operator<<` this returns the same object you passed and hence can concatenate the calls

Comment: But what's the problem if I return a copy ?

Comment: @ИвелинИванов • When you return a copy, you are getting a copy.  When you modify the copy, you are modifying the copy.  `vec << string << string;` modifies the original and returns a copy, then modifies the copy (which does not modify the original).  Then discards the copy.

Comment: @ИвелинИванов the copy is too short-lived to be of any use. If you don's assign the copy to anything, it just a temporary and gone at the end of the line. Any work you perform on it is wasted, so and the compiler stops you from doing it.

Comment: @ИвелинИванов "what's the problem if I return a copy" - That then modifications will only affect the copy and not the original object.

Comment: @ИвелинИванов, I suggest you turn on all compiler warnings and compile. How did compiler not warn you? Also, SO gods, shallow/deep copy does not play part here, does it?

Comment: @ИвелинИванов Copy means copy, it does not mean a reference to the original. A copied object is a different object to the object it was copied from.

Comment: But It doesn't it copy the vec in this case ?